Integration testing an Angular App with Entra sign in with Nightwatch
I am developing an Angular App. This Angular only way to authenticate is via Microsoft Entra. But the question is possibly valid any Oauth + MFA enabled app.
Can anyone tell how to create tests if 99% of the app is only available signin?
I do know what to do with simple user name + password. But now I am wondering what to do with the Oauth worflow?
